# Difference Between Webpack and Express?

Tags: express, webpack-dev-server

New to Webpack.

Using Webpack I can create a server. At the same time I can also use express to create a server. What then is the difference between the two and when to use webpack-dev-server and express servers?

Answer (score 10):

They're completely unrelated.

Webpack is a modular bundler which can take all of your JS, CSS, HTML, etc., and crank out a set files where they are merged as necessary.

Express is a framework for handling HTTP requests in your Node.js application on the server.

Comment: Would be useful to know how webpack-dev-server compares to express server, part of the original question which is still unaddressed.